# CartoDB map export

Tags: carto

Any document on how to transfer CartoDB map into Splunk Dashboard and what are the steps I need to perform ? I have created the map already

I have CartoDB / Torque Map application installed in Splunk, how to use the Search Patterns, so I can start Torque animation?